# how to print a Double without commas

Tags: java, formatting, double

When using `toString()`, Double adds commas (5143 is printed as 5,143).
How to disable the commas?

Comment: I don't get a separator with this code:  String str = Double.toString(5143);

Comment: @tur1ng: your locale settings are different from Erik's settings. @Bozho: it's not a decimal separator, it's a *thousands separator* used to group digits in some locales. Quite a weird practice, IMHO - to further mess things up, the same symbol (,) is used as a decimal separator in some locales.

Comment: It is not necessarily decimal separator. For example, in Russian locale `,` is a digit grouping symbol, while decimal separator is `.`. So what looks as `5143.5` in US locale is `5,143.5` in Russian one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem belongs to Locale, as pointed out correctly by Rorick. However, you should look into [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class, in case changing Locale means mess up all the things.

Look at [NumberFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class, to deal with thousand separator. Because it seems your case is regarding thousand separator instead.

Answer (score 9):

This will remove all grouping (in your case commas).

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setGroupingUsed(false);
```

Answer (score 7):

As far as I am aware, you can not disable what the `toString()` method returns.

My solution would be as follows:

```
someDouble.toString().replaceAll(",", "");
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: It's a hack, not a solution, imho.

Comment: +1 because I wrote the same :). I don't find it 'not elegant' (and even better than the locale handling in the other post), cause it has no side effects and does exactly what is intended.

Comment: @Rorick: It's not only a solution, it's the best one.

Comment: If only your program is for your personal home usage.

Comment: If you want no commas, it's a everywhere-solution. If you want no separators  at all you have to enhanced it (but similar!!). If you want to solve this by manipulating the locale, you have side effects and you can't be sure what's happening somewhere else or you need to run the program in Romania (and everywhere else) with your US locale.
So if the problem is to format Doubles (and not Dates or Currencies or ....) then solve it by formatting Doubles.

 >If only your program is for your personal home usage.<
The opposite is true.

Comment: Caution! This won't work with some Locale

Answer (score 5):

Java has excellent support for formatting numbers in text in different locales with the [NumberFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class:

With current locale:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(5000000);
```

will get you (with swedish locale) the string: 5 000 000

...or with a specific locale (e.g. french, which also results in *5 000 000*):

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(5000000);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
myDouble.toString().replaceAll(",", "");
```

Comment: Checkout the Bozho's post there, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242878/how-to-print-a-double-without-commas/2242921#2242921. His point is quite valid and make a lot of sense.

Comment: I have to admit I don't get his point at all... It seems like he's talking about the decimal separator and not the digit group separator (which this question is about).

Comment: @kai1968: The example he provided is of integer value, and mentioned that, `Double` adds comma. So, I tend to agree. I think he needs to come back to clear the confusion here.

Comment: What would keep this from misbehaving in a locale where the decimal separator is ",", and myDouble is a fraction like 1.5? In many European locales what Americans write as 1.5 will be formatted as "1,5" which this code would convert to "15".  N'est-ce pas?

Answer (score 4):

I use this method to format a double to string with a fixed locale, no grouping and with 
a minimum and maximum of fraction digits

```
public String formatNumber(double number){
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en", "EN"));
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);  
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
    nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
    String str = nf.format(number);
    return str;       
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably, you have to change your locale settings. It is taken by default from system locale, but you can override this. Read javadoc on [Locale](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) class and this [little tutorial](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/locale.html) to start. Locale can be specified through command line:

```
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US MyApplication
```

Comment: +1. Actually I was in the midst of writing the same thing. Anyways, I wrote a complementary post. :)

Answer (score 3):

Three ways:

1. Using the `DecimalFormat`

   ```
   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
   DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = df.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
   dfs.setGroupingSeparator(Character.MAX_VALUE);
   df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
   System.out.println(df.format(doubleVar));
   ```
2. (as suggested by others) just replace the comma in the string that you get
3. Set the locale on load of your VM

Answer (score 2):

NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();

format.setGroupingUsed(false);

Comment: This is incomplete and seems redundant.  Where does NumberFormat get imported from?

Answer (score -2):

```
Double result= 5143.0;

Sysout(result.toString())
```

gives me `5143.0...` can u put the code for which u got so