# Java: Format double with decimals

Tags: java, objective-c, formatting, double, decimal

In Objective C I have been using this code to format a value so that a value with zero decimals will be written without decimals and a value with decimals will be written with one decimal:

```
CGFloat value = 1.5;
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*f",(value != floor(value)),value];

//If value == 1.5 the output will be 1.5
//If value == 1.0 the output will be 1
```

I need to do the same thing for a double value in Java, I tried the following but that is not working:

```
return String.format("%.*f",(value != Math.floor(value)),value);
```

Comment: May be [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) helps you. ????  :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [how to print a Double without commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242878/how-to-print-a-double-without-commas/2242917#2242917). This will definitely provide you some idea.

Precisely, this will do

```
DecimalFormat.getInstance().format(1.5)
DecimalFormat.getInstance().format(1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Is it possible to set the maximum decimals for this? So for example 1.425 will show as 1.5?

Comment: Martin, then you should make use of `Math.floor()` or `Math.round()`, before formatting -- as it is not at all about formatting any more.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like?

```
return value == (long) value ? ""+(long) value : ""+value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it with String.format("..") method, but you can achieve the same using java.text.DecimalFormat; See this code sample:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
class Test {
public static void main(String... args) {
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat();
        System.out.println(formatter.format(1.5));
        System.out.println(formatter.format(1.0));
   }
}
```

The output is 1.5 and 1 respectively.