# How not to get a comma on the output?

Tags: java

```
    NumberFormat df = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits (2);
    df.setMinimumFractionDigits (2);

    double[] floatValues = new double[5];
    String Input;

    Input = stdin.readLine();
    String[] floatValue = Input.split("\\s+");      

    while (letter != 'q' && letter != 'Q'){
        for (int i = 0; i < floatValue.length; ++i){
        floatValues[i] = Double.parseDouble (floatValue[i]);

        System.out.println("LWL:" + df.format((floatValues[1])));
        System.out.println("Hull Speed:" + df.format(1.34 * Math.sqrt(floatValues[1])));
```

This is part of the code, I'm suppose to input 5 numbers like: 34.5 24.0 10.2 11200 483. My program runs perfectly, the only problem is that the output is suppose to be 11200 and I get 11,200. How do I get it to not output the comma. Thank You.

Comment: `result.replaceAll(",", "");` ?

Comment: If you are using `DecimalFormat`, it is a locale issue. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242878/how-to-print-a-double-without-commas

Comment: How did you create `df`? Can you share that part of the code too please?

Answer (score 2):

This is the issue:

```
NumberFormat df = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
```

That's getting the format for your machine's default locale, which presumably uses a comma as the decimal point. Just use the US locale:

```
NumberFormat df = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
```

That will then use a dot for the decimal point regardless of your machine's locale.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`df.setGroupingUsed(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setGroupingUsed-boolean-).
From [`java.text.NumberFormat.isGroupingUsed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#isGroupingUsed--):

> Returns true if grouping is used in this format. For example, in the English locale, with grouping on, the number 1234567 might be formatted as "1,234,567". The grouping separator as well as the size of each group is locale dependant and is determined by sub-classes of NumberFormat.

This will result in the output "11200.00". If you really want "11200", i.e. no fraction digits (contrary to your code), call [`df.setMaximumFractionDigits(0)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits-int-) and discard [`df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits-int-).